# is it right to use mixed ranges in NN attributes? some [0,1] and some [-1,1]

Tags: neural-network, normalization

This is my first ANN project and I'm trying to understand if i'm handling the data normalization correctly.

I have the following types of attributes
* Binary
* Numeric (which can be negative and positive)
* Numeric (that can be only positive)

1. Is it right that some of the attributes will spread on the range of [-1, 1] and some on  the range of [0, 1]
2. Is there any way to convert the positive data to spread on the range of [-1,1]?
3. Dose that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It is not necessarily 'bad', as long as you do it consistently. However, you have to lookup which values your neural networks take - if your network acccepts `[-1, 1]` as input, then it's advised to use all of this range. Is there a reason you want to use different ranges?
2. Ofcourse there is! [Check out this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70808/147931)
3. A neural network doesnt need to know if a number was positive or negative before normalization. As long as you normalize each input consistently, then it won't be  a problem.

---

Edit after your comment:

You should really figure out if your neural network library *accepts* `[-1, 1]` in the first place.

If it does:

- Keep distances in the range `[0,1]`
- Keep normal (negative) number in the range `[-1,1]`

If it doesnt:

- Keep distances AND all other values in range `[0,1]`

That's how I would  do it. However you can test yourself what works best through trial and error.

Comment: some of the data (numeric, positive and negative) represent position so, so the delta representing the distance can be positive and negative. and some is edit distance between strings, so it can only be positive. It it right to use the min/max function for this?

Comment: @AdiDarachi I see what you mean now. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: 1. I use Tanh as the activation function, so the network can receive [-1, 1] range (dose that make sens?) .  2. it's better to keep the range 0-1 rather then -1 to 1 when -1 is worst and 1 is best? Thanks is advanced